# Can you change the default ink color in PowerPoint 2016 for ALL presentations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I know that you can change the default pen color for a given presentation in the slideshow tab, but that only applies to the one presentation, which for my purposes is only slightly better tha

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  You can't set the default pen color for all presentations.

The properties for various things in PPT are scattered here and there.

Some, application-level properties that control PPT itself or set defaults for ALL presentations, are stored in the Windows registry ( or prefs files on Mac ).

Then there are presentation-level properties, things that apply to only one specific presentation.  These are recorded in the individual presentation files.  Pen color is one of these, unfortunately for your purposes.

In some cases (usually not documented by MS for use by us mortals), there are registry settings that override PPT's built-in defaults.  I don't know of any that set pen color, though.